# Highlight and find position (row & column) of matching cells in two Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets I am comparing dynamically for matching values.
The position of the columns can be anywhere in the sheet, and the script will still work.

I want to find the `row` and `column` position values of the matching cells in both sheets in `for loop` and highlight those cells.

I was able to it for values in the CASES sheet, but I can't find the row value of the matching cell in the IMPORT sheet to do the background highlight in the IMPORT sheet.

I am not interested in doing it using conditional formatting.

Thank you.

**Link to sheet demo: [DEMO SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RBUQiggqYPZyiHgA9Q57Bf7WZr0H9pqqCIvdUuc4NJI/edit?usp=sharing)**

[image: CASES Sheet ready example]

[image: Execution log]

**My Code:**

```
function compareSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Load all Casen Number columns values into array
  var importValues = getColumnValues("Case Number", "IMPORT");
  var casesValues = getColumnValues("Case Number", "CASES");
  // Convert Casen Number columns values into 1D array
  var newImportValues = importValues.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });
  var newCasesValues = casesValues.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });


  for (var i in newCasesValues) {
    var matchedCase = newImportValues.indexOf(newCasesValues[i])
    if (matchedCase !== -1) {
      
      // If found then... 
      
      // HIGHLIGHT MATCHING CELL IN CASES TAB
      var tempCasesColIndex = getColumnIndex("Case Number", "CASES")
      ss.getSheetByName("CASES").getRange(+i + 2, tempCasesColIndex).setBackground("orange")
      Logger.log("Case match found in CASES sheet at row: " + (+i + 2) + " & column: " + tempCasesColIndex)

      // HIGHLIGHT MATCHING CELL IN IMPORT TAB
      var tempImportColIndex = getColumnIndex("Case Number", "IMPORT")
      Logger.log("Case match found in IMPORT sheet at row: " + "???" + " & column: " + tempImportColIndex)
      //ss.getSheetByName("IMPORT").getRange(???, tempImportColIndex).setBackground("green")

    } else {
      
      // If NOT found then...
      // Clear the cell formatting
      var tempCasesColIndex = getColumnIndex("Case Number", "CASES")
      ss.getSheetByName("CASES").getRange(+i + 2, tempCasesColIndex).setBackground(null)
    }
  }

}

// Load Case Number column values
function getColumnValues(label, sheetName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Get column number for Case Number
  var colIndex = getColumnIndex(label, sheetName);

  // Get number of rows in Case Number
  var numRows = ss.getLastRow() - 1;

  // Load Case Number values into array
  var colValues = ss.getRange(2, colIndex, numRows, 1).getValues();

  return colValues;

}

// Get column name index value
function getColumnIndex(label, sheetName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Find last column
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();

  // Load headers into array
  var lookupRangeValues = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, lc).getValues()[0];

  // Search for label and return the column number
  var index = lookupRangeValues.indexOf(label) + 1;

  return index;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix this problem after I found a YT video explaining the method `findIndex`.
Now I can return the position of the matching values from both sheets.

If anyone is interested:
**[Link to the video - Array find( ) and findIndex( ) Methods explained](https://youtu.be/9b6gxQZHvis)**

```
  // Find matching cell row number in the IMPORT sheet
  let tempImportRowIndex = newImportValues.findIndex(item => {
    if (newCasesValues[i] === item) return true;
  });
  tempImportRowIndex = tempImportRowIndex + 2;
```

[image: Final Execution Log]